# Inheritance on Test Classes

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm having problems adding some code to setup method on my BaseClass for tests

This is my BaseClass

```
class TestBaseClass(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps['app'] = os.getcwd()+"/package/debug.apk"
    desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.nopp.pmp'
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
    print "Parent Method"
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    self.driver.set_network_connection(4)
```

And on a separate file :

```
class ChildTests(TestBaseClass):
def test_childClass(self):
    print "Child"
    main_page = MainPageTests.test_this(self)
    assert True
```

When I execute my test on ChildTest Class I don't get to see the printing from Parent nor the setting up on network connectivity. Since ChildTest inherits from Base shouldn't it work?
Thanks

Comment: this isnt an answer, but my advice to you is "just use pytest"

Comment: The indentation is off (setUp should be indented relative to the class statement)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to strip your code down to the bare minimum:

`TestBaseClass.py`:

```
import unittest

class TestBaseClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print("setUp() in Parent Method")
```

`ChildTests.py`:

```
from TestBaseClass import TestBaseClass

class ChildTests(TestBaseClass):
    def test_childClass(self):
        print("Child")
```

What I get is:

```
~/tmp/test$ pytest ChildTests.py
==========================  ChildTests.py  ===========================
setUp() in Parent Method
Child
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```